Dynamic scoping evaluation
I'm currently taking a course about programming languages and trying to solve the following question, given the code in SML syntax, assume SML using dynamic scoping, what would be the value of the last 2 lines
val (x,t) = (13,50);

fun zod x = (x+t);

local 
  val t = zod (x+t) 
in 
  fun foo x = zod (x+t) 
end;

val t = ~40;

fun bar x = 
  let 
    val t = zod (x+t) 
  in 
    foo (x+t) 
  end;

val t = 60;

foo(x+t);
bar(x+t);

Our book states that the answers should be 193, 652 but it doesn't give explanation.
As I understand the concept, the first call should works like that:
calling foo(13+60) than the local exp evaluate t = zod(13+60) = 13+60+60 = 133 than it calls zod(73+133) but now t is changed to 133 so the final value should be 73+133+133=339 but somehow it's not the case and any other options I try does not yield 193, what am I missing here?
P.S: apparently the local block does not evaluate when using dynamic scoping, any explanation for that?

Are you sure you copied the code correctly/completely? I don't see a definition of y anywhere in the code.

Let's start with the last question, because that's actually the point:

P.S: apparently the local block does not evaluate when using dynamic scoping, any explanation for that?

The local block is outside foo, hence it is evaluated when foo is defined, not when it is called. That's what distinguishes it from the let expression inside bar.
Knowing that, evaluation works as follows (I'm assuming that the actual calls were meant to be foo(x+t) and bar (x+t)):
foo(x+t)
= foo(13+60)            (* because the most recent binding for t is 60 *)
= foo 73
= zod(73+t)
= zod(73+60)            (* because t = 60 still is the most recent binding *)
= zod 133
= 133+t
= 133+60                (* same *)
= 193

bar(x+t)
= bar(13+60)            (* as before *)
= bar 73
= let val t = zod(73+60) in foo(73+t) end
= let val t = zod 133 in foo(73+t) end
= let val t = 133+t in foo(73+t) end
= let val t = 133+60 in foo(73+t) end
= let val t = 193 in foo(73+t) end     (* t is locally rebound here *)
= foo(73+193)
= foo 266
= zod(266+t)
= zod(266+193)          (* because the most recent binding for t is now 193! *)
= zod(459)
= 459+t
= 459+193               (* still so! *)
= 652

This presentation is a bit simplistic btw, it is important to also understand that the local binding t = 193 is only active until the end of the let expression containing it. After that, t would fall back to its previous value 60. But that's not exercised by these examples.
